# Sort Active Processes in Unix

Tags: unix, monitoring, performance-monitoring, process

How can i sort active processes by total process time in unix?

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

`ps -A -o cmd,etime --sort etime`

If by 'process time' you mean elapsed wall clock time of the process. Other time options are:

```
   j     cutime       cumulative user time
   J     cstime       cumulative system time
   k     utime        user time
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you well, you can run `top` and press `T`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `ps Ok` (O - order, k - user time), and apply selection and formatting options as needed.

Comment: See @Kyle Brandts answer, it's better and more comprehensive.